# Should I update read model on each event

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I have `Customer` read model that needs to be updated after `NewOrderEvent`.

One thing i want to understand, should i update my read model on every event. Or i need to replay all events and replace read model.

What im doing now is:

1. Saving `NewOrderEvent`
2. Getting or creating `Customer` read model
3. Invoking `Customer.ApplyEvent(NewOrderEvent)` that changes `Customer` state.
4. Saving `Customer` read model

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually yes, you want to update the read model every time you have an event. But, it's just a simple CRUD operation, a db update. The replaying of events is done when you want to (re)generate a new read model, because you could have millions of events and could be a very long running operation.

Btw, the apply stuff should be reserved for command model only, in order to avoid confusion. You apply events to a domain aggregate root (entity), but you use an event as the source of data for read model updates.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on "apply" part. Also isn`t it possible that in some case domain aggregate root is actually a read model?

Comment: If you're using CQRS a domain aggregate is never a read model. A read model is just a bunch of data structures tailored for querying scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. You may decide to replay the stream of events in order to recreate the read model only if you introducing something new to it.

Some people rebuild read models whenever the schema changes, but in many cases you can use migrations for that. Really depends on your application.